# How to check array value have file format

Tags: javascript

How to check that array values all are HTML files? If the array is not entirely strings ending in `.html`, I want to show an `alert` message and stop it. How can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/p57cjk81/2/

```
var arr = ["power.html", "sugar.html", "time.html", "kavi.html", "images.html"];
//var arr=["power.txt", "sugar.html", "time.html", "kavi.html", "images.html"];

var flag = true;

for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {

  if (arr[i].split(.) == ".html"){
    flag = true;
  } else {
    flag = false;
  }

}

if (flag) {
  alert("Yes all the file have html");
} else {
  alert("All file are not html");  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const allHtml = (arr) => 
  !arr.some(
    f => { let parts = f.split("."); return parts.length!=2 || parts[1] !== "html"}
  );

let arr1=["power.html","sugar.html","time.html","kavi.html","images.html"];
let arr2=["power.html","sugar.jpg","time.html","kavi.html","images.html"];

console.log(
  allHtml(arr1),   
  allHtml(arr2)
);
  
// suggested usage:

var msg = allHtml(arr1) ? "Yes":"Not";
msg += " all the files have html extension in array";
alert(msg);
```

Comment: Change `if (flag)` to `if (allHtml(arr))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and a regex which matches strings with some content ending in `.html` using the `$` end-of-line anchor:

```js
const arr = ["power.html", "sugar.html", "time.html", "kavi.html", "images.html"];

console.log(arr.every(e => /.+\.html$/.test(e)));
```

Comment: Nice. I immediately thought of some and you of the opposite :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
var arr=["power.html","sugar.html","time.html","kavi.html","images.html"];

if(arr.every(e => /\.html$/.test(e))){
  alert("Yes all the file have html");
}
else{
  alert("All file are not html");
}
```